# I am in a basic level of laravel9 and trying to save() or update() in a database and this error happen Attempt to assign property "name" on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

[this is the controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO1yM.png) 
[and this is the route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjfgW.png)
and this is the blade code:

```
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5 w-25" >
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <p class="fs-1">Update Members</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form class="row g-3" action="/update" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="id" class="form-label">Id</label>
          <input type="hidden" value="{{$data['id']}}" class="form-control "  id="id">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$data['Name']}}"  id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$data['Email']}}" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$data['Address']}}" id="address">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$data['Phone']}}" id="phone">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
          <hr class="border border-primary border-3 opacity-75">
        </div>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I am trying to save this four columns in the database name email address and phone
then this error happened.
please answer me quickly if you can?

[I am trying to save data in these columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7ka.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please do not put up images of code; code is text and belongs in your question as text in a code block

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that, in the controller, $data is null. You can make the code fail by changing "find" to "findOrFail". The code will return a NotFoundException. Then you can investigate why $data is null.

Read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is probably in your update function it should be like this:

```
function update(Request $req){
$data = Member::find($req->id);

$data->Name = $req->Name;
$data->Email= $req->Email;
$data->Address = $req->Address;
$data->Phone = $req->Phone;
$data->save();

return redirect()->input();
}
```

in your update function you have changed the upper case to a lower case which will cause the Attempt to assign property "name" on null Error